# How to ask someone to spar?

Tags: phrase-request

I remember reading this many times, probably in novels, this form of asking someone to spar:

> ...to exchange some...

maybe something like, “Do want to exchange some blows?”

I'm not using it in a narrating form, like "disciples exchange some...” and wonder if there is something more appropriate.

Comment: What's wrong with "let's spar?" Also note that "exchange some blows" _without context_ has a possible vulgar sexual interpretation and may be misinterpreted as such by some speakers. I would avoid saying it in that way.

Comment: @TypeIA I need it because I'm not using it in a narrating from, like "disciples exchange some ..., and thank you for that note about the possible vulgar interpretation.

Comment: exchange blows cannot be construed as vulgar. My goodness!

Comment: @TypeIA it could be used, I already gave an example, like 'want to exchange some blows?' it's just that I thought there's something more appropriate. And I found it,  'want to exchange a few blows?' and the one I was looking for is 'exchange pointers', i read this a lot in novels. thank you for your help guys

Comment: to exchange blows is not a spoken expression said by one friend, etc. to another. It is descriptive and means two people fight. Of course, I could say: I saw them in the parking lot and they exchanged blows. [hit each other]. And it's definitely not sexual.

Comment: @habibhassani "exchange pointers" is totally different and refers to a conversation in which people share ideas, suggestions, tips and/or lessons learned about a topic. It isn't a physical activity like sparring. I really think "sparring" is a good fit and don't understand the perceived need to find something better, regardless of what else you may have encountered.

Comment: My remark about this not being about anything sexual was removed. What should have been removed is the one suggesting that. exchange blows is simply not sexual.

Comment: There are many ways to convey you want to fight them. Here is one: "You wanna take this outside son"

Comment: @TypeIA It would be very difficult for anyone to interpret it sexually, unless they're the type of person who could interpret *anything* sexually. In short, you'd have to really work at it to think of it that way. I also object to equating *sexual* with *vulgar*, which is even more of a leap.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica I didn't equate them, I combined them. What I described is both vulgar and sexual. There was no suggestion that one implies or equates to the other. And I respectfully but strongly disagree that this interpretation **without context** (this is crucial!) is difficult to reach.

Comment: @TypeIA I *personally* find you thinking that the phrase *exchange some blows* to be either sexual or vulgar (let alone both) bizarre. I know of nobody else who could make that kind of association, and it just seems like a mostly incompressible assumption to me.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica Try approaching random people on the street and asking them if they would like to exchange some blows. I can't speak for the U.K. but I can absolutely guarantee you in the U.S. it would not take long at all to find someone who makes this interpretation.

Comment: @TypeIA I just did a quick Google search on the phrase. Every result describes fighting. I couldn't find any objective source for the interpretation you're describing. If you have a URL for a site that ascribes that meaning to it, please provide it. Otherwise, I can only think it's a localized or regional interpretation that I've never encountered before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In descriptions in novels or articles, one might find:

to exchange blows. That is descriptive, but not really conversational.

[exchange blows](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/exchange-blows-with-somebody)

to hit each other. But it does not mean to spar (boxing).

However, if you want to spar with a friend, you might say:

- How about we **go a few rounds**?
- Do you want to spar?